# Loading content from server without postback

Tags: asp.net, slider

I have a div and inside that I need to show a slide of divs. On the page load there would be only 3 div slides but when all three divs are displayed on the next button press I want to load some more divs (actually I have data on a sql database, I need to get them and print on the page a slide divs) on each next button press. (Asp.net)

How do I achieve this? what's the best way? Ajax, javascript, jquery. Show me a way.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be many possiblities but you can use asp.net update panel avialable in [**ASP.net ajax control toolkit**](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/), it will be easy for you to integrate and you need to do very small work at your end.

The other option is using [**jQuery ajax**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) it could reletively more efficent and gives you more control but it will require good javascript/ jQuery skills. This [tutorial](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/) is good starting point for using jQuery ajax with asp.net.